# ¿Cómo guardar la salida de una operación para usarla en la misma operación?

Tags: python, bucles

Intento hacer un programa que me encuentre todos los primos en un rango, desde el 5 hasta el número que se dé en el input.

Empecé haciendo el siguiente código:

```
nmax = int(input(«dime un numero: «))
for x in range(3, nmax):
    for i in range(3, x, 2):
        if x%i != 0:

            continue
        else:

            break 
    else:

        print ('%d es primo'%x)
```

y vi que era muy poco eficiente dividir entre cada uno de los números anteriores.

Lo que quiero ahora es guardar en memoria los primos que ya he descubierto y dividir solo entre ellos, habiendo colocado yo el 2, 3 y cinco para facilitarlo.

¿Cómo hacer que los propios primos que calcule mi operación se añadan a la lista de divisores para los siguientes números?

vale, ya solucione el problema, dejare el resultado por aqui, muchas gracias a todos los que ayudaron

```
  nmax=int(input("quiero todos los primos hasta el numero: "))
#hasta que numero buscaremos primos
primos=[2,3,5]
#aqui almacenamos los primos para dividir
def comprobarprimo():
    for n in range(5, nmax):
        for i in primos:
            if n%i !=0:
                #n no es divisble de i, aun puede ser primo
                continue

            else:
                #n es divisible entre i, es compuest0
                break
        else:
            #El bucle ha terminado con normalidad
            #Con certeza, n es primo
            print(n, "es primo")
            primos.append(n)

for x in primos:
    print(x, "es primo")


comprobarprimo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo hice con un for dentro de otro for, el primer for para recorrer desde 1 hasta el numero que introduzca el usuario.
Y en el otro for, se itera el numero dividiendo uno a uno, si el residuo es cero (0) aumenta el contador en 1. Como ya sabes si son mas de 2 los divisores, el numero no será primo:

```
nmax = int(input("dime un numero: "))
primos= []

for n in range(1,nmax+1):
   contador = 0

   for i in range(1,n+1):
       if n%i == 0:
           contador +=1
   if contador <= 2:
       primos.append(n)
    
print(f"los numeros primos entre 0 y {nmax} son: ",primos)
```

Si es primo guarda los valores en la lista primos, tal como tu ya lo tenias.

Comment: Hola @Juan. Recuerda que debes consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)». Debes explicar qué hace el código.

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea más eficiente el hacer otra comprobación para ver si el primo ya está encontrado, pero te comparto un código para encontrar los números primos.

```
def es_primo(num):
    for n in range(2, num):
        if num % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
def primos_en_rango(inicio, fin):
    primos = []
    for i in range(inicio,fin+1):
        if es_primo(i):
            primos.append(i)
    return primos
```

Entonces, al ejecutar: `primos_en_rango(1, 20)`, te devolverá `[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]`.

La primera función es para comprobar si un número es primo o no, y la segunda función es la que va a iterar en un rango y por cada número comprobará si es primo.